# Why flowers of "Ankada" are offered to Lord Hanuman?

Tags: hanuman

Why flowers of "Ankada" are offered to Lord Hanuman?

[image: flowers of ankada]

Comment: Aah these flowers, we used to play games with them during childhood. Being a devotee of Hanuman ji, i must know about this, but i cannot recall anyone using these flowers for worshipping.

Comment: In Sanskrit Ankada Flowers are called Arka (अर्क). I do not know the significance of using them like What is the result of worshiping with Ankada flowers or the story behind it, but it is mentioned in [Parasara Samhita Hanuman Charitam Chapter 49 (एकोन पञ्चाशत्पटलः)](http://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskritupload/parAsharasamhitAhanupatcharitra1.pdf) Sloka 5 that Arka flowers are used in Puja of Hanuman Ji. कुरण्ट स्थलपद्मानि केसरासन माधवीः ।
वनमल्ली कर्णिकारं **कुब्जार्के** चन्द्रकान्तकम् ॥ कुब्जार्के = कुब्ज+अर्के

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan (though it doesn't notify you) : Why did you convert it to comment? He actually cited the source and verse and it answers the question. He just doesn't know significance. But he has scripture which supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 11 indriyas and ankada represents all with its petals...  Hanumanji have asthasiddhi to control All indriyas.. Ankada gives us that message.   Hindu dharma is not baseless you can find only scientific things in that..  Best thing happened with me in this life...  Blessed